# Array - Check if array doesn't pick same value twice

Tags: php, arrays

I'm working on a script which rotates multiple slogans from an array. It picks a random array item and displays it, like so:

```
function sloganrotator_sc() {
    global $sloganrotator_options;

    $sentences = $sloganrotator_options['slogans'];
    $array = explode("\n", $sentences);

    if (count($array) > 1) {
        $randomize = array_rand($array);
        $result = $array[$randomize];

        return $result;
    } else {
        return $sloganrotator_options['slogans'];
    }
}
add_shortcode( 'slogan-rotator', 'sloganrotator_sc' );
```

What I'm trying to archieve is to check if the value on page 1 is not the same as on page 2.

For example: Before the page refresh, the value was 'Hello', after the refresh the value is 'Dogs'. I want to check if it doesn't pick the same item twice.

Something like this:

```
if($array[$randomize] == $result) {
    return 'Hold on, this one has already been shown!';
}
```

Sorry for my bad explanation, it's hard to explain..

Comment: per-user? use a session, per-site a db table

Comment: @Dagon Yes per user. How would that work with sessions?

Comment: store the selected text in a session. on the next page see if its the same as the random pick, if it is pick again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this :

```
if($array[$randomize] == $result) {
    return 'Hold on, this one has already been shown!';
}
```

to this :

```
if(isset($_SESSION['check']) AND !empty($_SESSION['check']) AND $_SESSION['check'] == $result){
    return 'Hold on, this one has already been shown!';
}
```